# Enter a value then it will show a different value in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

So I need to have a feature where a number (ID) is typed in a textbox and as I click the button, I need it to have a display value corresponding to the value inputted that would show on a different window.

[image]

I need to have the encircled one as a display value but I need to retain its value member which is an ID

This is my code at the first window:

```
private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PassingText = txtEvent.Text;
        PackingApproval pa = new PackingApproval();
        pa.Show();
    }
```

This is my code for the other window:

```
private void PackingApproval_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox4.Text = PackingList.PassingText;
    }
```

Note: the value I will show to the approval has a Corresponding value on the database

UPDATE: I have a code for calling the value from the database, but I cannot make it work since it needs to work between two windows

```
        private void PackingApproval_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox4.SelectedText = "EventID";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Juan Carlo SCM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=benilde");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT EventName FROM Event_Table WHERE EventID=@EventID", con);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("EventID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EventName", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        txtBox4.SelectedText = "EventID";
        txtBox4.Text = txtBox4.Tag.ToString();

        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the value by these ways:

> - **By constructor**

```
public partial class PackingApproval : Form
{
    public PackingApproval(string enterValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBox4.Text = enterValue;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = txtEvent.Text;
        PackingApproval pa = new PackingApproval(text);
        pa.Show();
    }
}
```

> - **By Property of destination object**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = txtEvent.Text;
        PackingApproval pa = new PackingApproval();
        pa.SetPackagingApprovalText = text;
        pa.Show();
    }
}

public partial class PackingApproval : Form
{
    private string _setPackagingApprovalText;
    public string SetPackagingApprovalText
    {
        get
        {
            return _setPackagingApprovalText;
        }
        set
        {
            txtBox4.Text = value;
            _setPackagingApprovalText = value;
        }
    }
    public PackingApproval()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

> - **By field in destination object + FormLoad**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = txtEvent.Text;
        PackingApproval pa = new PackingApproval();
        pa.SetPackagingApprovalText = text;
        pa.Show();
    }
}
public partial class PackingApproval : Form
{
    public string SetPackagingApprovalText;
    public PackingApproval()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PackingApproval_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox4.Text = SetPackagingApprovalText;
    }
}
```

> **for your database problem:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = txtEvent.Text;
        PackingApproval pa = new PackingApproval();
        pa.SetPackagingApprovalText = text;
        pa.Show();
    }
}

public partial class PackingApproval : Form
{
    public string SetPackagingApprovalText;
    public PackingApproval()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PackingApproval_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Juan Carlo SCM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=benilde");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT EventName FROM Event_Table WHERE EventID=@EventID", con);

        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EventID", int.Parse(SetPackagingApprovalText)));
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            txtBox4.Text = reader["EventName"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if the value I need to show has a value in the database?

Comment: have you ever worked with ADO.NET (SqlConnection,SqlCommand,...) or EntityFramework ?

Comment: Im currently using sql server then I set a connection from visual studio

Comment: did you write code for fetching data from database? if you wrote this kind of code, put your code here and update your post. I will help you, but if you don't write any code, look at these post to fetching data : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737517/1404642

Comment: I tried doing the similar way from the link you commented here but its still not doing the way I want it to

Comment: @JonathanSumilang Ask this in another question, its bad form and unfair to the people answer to keep changing your question

Comment: @JonathanSumilang I updated my answer and I solve your database problem too, is it okay ?

Comment: It doesn't show the value of the inputted id in the other window